# error in installing gnome-shell

Tags: installation, gnome

```
rstu2005@rstu2005-Aspire-5742:~$ sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
[sudo] password for rstu2005: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package gnome-shell is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'gnome-shell' has no installation candidate
rstu2005@rstu2005-Aspire-5742:~$
```

Answer (score 2):

Welcome Rohit.Run `synaptic package manager`,then check this line `Community-maintained free and open source-software(Universe)` from `Settings>Repositories`.Come to `terminal` and type this command `sudo apt-get update`.This should help you install `Gnome-shell`.

Comment: I didn't have `synaptic` installed, but I simply had to run `sudo apt-get update` first and then I was in business.

Answer (score 1):

Go to System Settings > Software & Updates
In the "Ubuntu Software" tab check the box:
"Community-maintained free and open-source software (universe).

Then in terminal run the command:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

After that's done, run the command:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
```

Then you should be able to run or replace the gnome-shell with:

```
gnome-shell --replace
```

Answer (score 0):

**This only works for Ubuntu 11.10 or newer**

Go to Software Center -> Edit -> Software Sources and activate universe. Then reload your packages (Click "Check" in the Update manager). Then you can install gnome-shell through apt-get or the Software Center.